# How do Clearview's curves of the lowercase a and u trend towards a square?

Tags: fonts

Is there a Typography Stack Exchange? Happy to post this there instead.

Can you pls explain [2:48](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eky17clTEeQ)? What does "trend towards this kind of squarish shape" mean??? The speaker is [Tobias Frere-Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobias_Frere-Jones). His remarks should be interpreted in contrast with the Highway Gothic typeface.

[image]

Comment: Only the author could say for sure, but it probably just means that they both fit into squares without too much extra white space (unlike say the l)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I reckon "trend towards" is a slip of the tongue. The expression is usually "tend towards". It means to have a tendency to display some behaviour or characteristic, in this particular case, a squarish shape - i.e. the letters would fit approximately within a square.  I have a feeling you would be better to ask questions like this on some of the English language related stack exchange sites instead.